# what are the basic performance issues raised in the Windows Applications?

Tags: c#-4.0

I wanna to know the basic performance factors while developing  a Windows applications?Could anyone explain me in detail?

Comment: No no no no no. You wil have to be a lot more specific than that.

Answer (score 1):

Start from that:
**Performance Tips and Tricks in .NET Applications:**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973839.aspx